# Electric field a distance z above the midpoint of a straight line segment

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

In Griffiths there's an example to evaluate the Electric field a distance z above the midpoint of a straight line segment of length 2L. Which carries a uniform charge  $\lambda$.

In that calculation, the author used the  fraction  of charges dq which placed on  the left and also the right side. Then he integrated from 0 to L (in 3rd Edition).

[image]

Why didn't he only pick the only left/right portion charge dq then integrate that from  0 to 2L? 
$$d\mathbf E=2\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{\lambda\:dx}{\mathcal r^2}\right)\cos\theta\:\hat{\mathbf z}$$

Answer (score 1):

He is making use of a well-chosen coordinate system to create a symmetric system. That greatly simplifies the concept and makes the integral easy.

I bet that somewhere, he doubles the result of the integral. He has also made an argument that the $x$-components will add to zero (again, using symmetry).

Choosing a coordinate system to create symmetry is a valuable skill. You should study this solution carefully and learn from Griffiths's technique.