# Electric field on a point at a height $z$ from the midpoint of a charged line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

First let me say I have already read the thread [Electric field a distance z above the midpoint of a straight line segment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200329/electric-field-a-distance-z-above-the-midpoint-of-a-straight-line-segment) concerning the exact same problem I'm talking about. Nevertheless, my question is different.

We want to get the electric field $\textbf{E}$ at a height $z$ over a uniformly charged line $\lambda$ of length $2L$. We know that, for a position vector $\textbf{p}$, the displacement vector $\textbf{r}$ and the Coulomb's constant $k_c$ we face the path integral

$$ \textbf{E}(\textbf{p}) = k_c \lambda \int_\Gamma\frac{\hat{\textbf{r}}}{r^2}\cdot \mathrm d\textbf{l}$$

We realize that the non-vertical components of the vector will cancel out, but that the vertical component will conspire, so we can solve this problem studying only the vertical component of $\textbf{E}$, $E_z$.

Nevertheless, I wonder how would we solve the problem without anticipating this mutual cancellation of the $\textbf{r}$ vectors. Particularly I think that we should have

$$\mathrm d\textbf{l} = \mathrm dx\, \hat{\textbf{x}} \Rightarrow \frac{\hat{\textbf{r}}}{r^2}\cdot \mathrm d\textbf{l} = \frac{x}{(x^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,\mathrm dx$$

But this should lead to

$$k_c\lambda\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{x}{(x^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,\mathrm dx = 0$$

which is a definitely incorrect result. So, I have two questions:

1. What is wrong with my reasoning?
2. How would this problem be solved without anticipating, simply by solving the path integral? Specifically I'm interested in seeing a correct parametrization.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
The reason why I say that the result seems incorrect is because it differs from the given solution:

[image: solution screenshot]

Comment: Your last formula is the integral of an odd function on an interval symmetric with respect to the origin. Therefore, it is zero. Why do you think that this is "a definitely incorrect result"? It looks definitely correct to me.

Comment: I like to express the unit vector as the vector "r" divided by the scaler "r", which leads directly to your final integral; except the numerator should be the x component of r, which is -x. Either way, when you evaluate at the limits, the result is zero. Whats the problem?

Comment: My solution defers from the one given as correct.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you were concentrating only on the component of $\vec{E}$ parallel to the line, in a point on the median plane of the line. In that case, zero would have been the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula for $\mathbf{E}$ contains a mistake: that scalar product should not be there, and you should have the scalar $\mathrm{dl}$ in place of the vector $\mathrm{d} \mathbf{l}$. That is, the formula should read:
$$ \mathbf{E} ( \mathbf{p}) = k_c \lambda \int_\Gamma \frac{\mathbf{\hat{r} }}{r^2} \mathrm{dl} $$

To see this, let's split the line in tiny segments of length $s$. If they are very tiny, we can consider them as point charges, each one with charge $\lambda s$. Then the electric field at $\mathbf{p}$ is
$$ \mathbf{E} ( \mathbf{p}) = k_c \sum_i \lambda s \frac{\mathbf{\hat{r}}_i}{r_i^2} $$
where the sum runs over the segments and $r_i$ is the distance between $\mathbf{p}$ and the $i$-th segment, while $ \mathbf{\hat{r}} _i$ is the unit vector pointing from this segment to $\mathbf{p} $.

Now let the segments become infinitely short and infinitely many. Then the sum over segments is replaced by a path integral, and the length $s$ is replaced by the "infinitesimal length" $\mathrm{dl}$. In conclusion, you get the integral I wrote down at the beginning of this post.

My formula becomes equivalent to yours if we replace vector $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ with its component in the direction of $\mathrm{d} \mathbf{l}$. This means that you didn't calculate the full vector $\mathbf{E}$, but only the vector's component in the direction of the line. That component is obviously zero, as you obtained.